# Mapbox Loaded Event

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox to render a map with an layer from rainviewer.  The code is working but I need to synchronize with the end of the layer rendering.  I need to know when the last layer is rendered and the image is complete. I need to do this because I'm rendering the HTML in puppeteer.  Using any of the networkidle options does not work.  There does not seem to be any event on the Map object that signals this either.

I did scour the forums, etc. looking for a solution but did not find anything that would work specifically in this scenario.

Comment: There is a [years-long thread](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6707) on this topic with some workarounds

Comment: Several of them: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6076

Answer (score 2):

This is a generally broken use case in Mapbox-GL-JS. One option that may work for you is:

`map.once('idle', () => ...)`

This fires once the map has come to rest, completely painted.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i tried this but the event is never triggered.

map.once('idle', function() { console.log('A idle event occurred.'); });

Comment: OK, that was my fault.  my HTML was using a very old version of mapbox-gl-js. updating to the new version fixes it and i now get the event.

Comment: I render multiple layers, one of which is many polygons. The map.on('idle', ...) event considers the map idle after the smaller layers are rendered, and before the larger one has finished. So my stop spinner and hide please wait message actions happen while the big layer is still rendering.